# How do I search all dependent views created from tables within a whole schema?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to find all views created referencing tables from a single schema as I need to alter the views to point to a different table which is actively being pushed with data. E.g. Schema.Table1 is redundant and Schema.Table2 is now the table which needs to be used so all views dependent on Schema.Table1 will need to be altered to use data from Schema.Table2.

I have used the following code to generate all dependent views from a single table within the schema, however due to the amount of tables being able to search with the schema instead of the table name would be beneficial:

```
SELECT 'SCHEMA.TABLE1' as [View Name],referencing_schema_name, referencing_entity_name, referencing_id, referencing_class_desc, is_caller_dependent  
FROM sys.dm_sql_referencing_entities ('SCHEMA.TABLE1', 'OBJECT')
UNION
SELECT 'SCHEMA.TABLE2' as [View Name],referencing_schema_name, referencing_entity_name, referencing_id, referencing_class_desc, is_caller_dependent  
FROM sys.dm_sql_referencing_entities ('SCHEMA.TABLE2', 'OBJECT')
```

From the results I would need to see Schema Name, Table Name and View/ Stored Procedure Name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below -

```
select v.name
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS iv
join sys.views v on v.name = iv.Table_Name
where iv.Table_Catalog = 'Your database name'
```

Comment: You post before the edit gave me the correct answer in finding all views created under the schema. Is there any way this can be joined with Stored Procedure data information similarly.

Comment: @MitchellDeane, it just because you can use the database name instead of a single table name

Comment: Ah, I've added the where 'and iv.VIEW_DEFINITION like '%schema%' back in and it works, thank you.